# NodeJS import NPM module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a .js file that I am trying run through node.  The problem that I am having is that my file requires an import of i18next.  Node of course does not like this.

I have already added `"type":"module` to my `package.json`.  Inside my file `accessLayer.js` I am trying to import i18next as:

`import i18next from 'i18next'; const {languageTranslate} = i18next;`

For my code inside my terminal I am running:

```
>node --experimental-repl-await
>var aa
>import("./app/accessLayer.js").then(loaded => aa = loaded)
```

if I `console.log()` aa it returns `[Module: null prototype] {  }`.

Inside my file is a `modules.export` which has an authenticate that I am trying to access.

Now, if I completely remove the i18next import from `accessLayer.js`.  I can then run:

```
>node
>var x
>var y
>var x = require('./app/accessLayer.js')
> var y = x()
> y.authenticate('xxxx')
```

This way does work, however, then I do not have access to i18next, which is needed.  Any advice or direction is greatly appreciated.  My version of node is: 14.17.6.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
import * as i18next from 'i18next';
```